# Worklight Console can not be opened because the Worklight Server is not running

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I'm just getting started with some of the samples at the Getting Started site, working with the Developers Edition. Whenever I Open Worklight Console, the eclipse environment abends. I'm sure I missed a set up item, but all seemed to install well. I appreciate any help / direction. Thanks.

I tried to post an image of the error, but stackoverflow indicates I need 10 reputations to post an image. Go figure.

The first line is Java was started but returned exit code=8096

There are some hits on this indicating that the license may not be compatible with the Rational license installed. Not sure what to do with that.

There's another post indicating Environment Variable corruption, but I don't have the corrupt Temp environment variables indicated.

Comment: host the error image elsewhere and provide a link.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow has a FAQ explaining what one can and cannot do and when. [It makes sense. Read it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

---

Did you at least create a new Worklight project and application?

If you do that and run the application by right-clicking on the application in the project tree and choose `Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server` this will: start the server + build the app + deploy the app.

Then you can right-click on the project icon and choose `Open Worklight Console` and you will see the console...

So unless you have some errors preventing the server from loading, the above should work.

1. Host the image elsewhere, like imgur.com
2. Explain what you have installed in your Eclipse. Which Eclipse is it? Did you install *only* Worklight Studio, or another plug-in in addition? Which?
3. What are those "hits" you mention? Elaborate.

---

Searching for the exit code in Google, I see the following IBM tech notes:

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21303648
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21567836
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21627887

Perhaps one of them is relevant for you as well.

Comment: i am not getting this menu  Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server pls tell me how to get it

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed Idan's advice to Run on Worklight Development Server and it is still not started, try this:

1. Switch to the Servers view (on the bottom pane of Eclipse by default).
2. Check your Worklight Development Server status
3. Right-click and select Clean...
4. Select OK when prompted to discard all publish start.
5. Redeploy your app using Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server

I am not sure if this would clean up your environment variable error message as I have not seen that one, but it has helped with several other errors that have caused my server to not start or run properly. (The most common one I get is an Out of Memory in the server.)

Comment: i am not getting this menu  Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server pls tell me how to get it